# Populate php variable ldap

Tags: php, variables, ldap, variable-assignment

I am new to PHP and would like to populate the variable $email with the LDAP attribute called "mail". I have used this code to do this:

$email = $info[$i]["mail"][0];

However, I don't get any return value. Is this the correct syntax for populating the variable $email and if not, can someone tell me how to populate the $email variable with the ldap attribute "mail".

When i do the echo statements to print out the ldap attributes, I am able to see the values such as below:

First Name: Jim
Last Name: Smith
Email: jimsmith@mycompany.com

Thanks, much appreciated

Code is below:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   $connect;
   $ldap_host='xxxx.mycompany.com';
   $ldap_admin_dn='cn=xxxxx,ou=xxxxxx,ou=aaa,ou=administrators,dc=xxxx,dc=ca';
   $ldap_pass='#####';
   $ldap_basedn='ou=people, dc=xxxx, dc=com';
    if(!($connect = ldap_connect($ldap_host))){
         die("Could not connect to $ldap_host");
    }

    if(!($bind = ldap_bind($connect, $ldap_admin_dn, $ldap_pass))){
        die("Could not bind to $connect");
    }

    $netlinkID = "test";
    $search = ldap_search($connect, $ldap_basedn, "uid=$netlinkID");
    $info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $search);

    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
       echo"<h3>Requestor Info</h3>";
       echo "<div class=\"col1\">First Name:" . "<span class=\"req-firstname\">" . $info[$i]["givenname"][0]. "</span></div>";
       echo "<div class=\"col1\">Last Name:" . "<span class=\"req-lastname\">" . $info[$i]["sn"][0]. "</span></div>";
       echo "<div class=\"col1\">Email: " . "<span class=\"req-email\">" . $info[$i]["mail"][0]. "</span></div>";

     //How to populate variable email to get value from the LDAP Mail attribute
     $email = $info[$i]["mail"][0];
     }

ldap_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: check what `ldap_count_entries($connect, $search)` returns, if it returns 0 then you didn't have any entries matched your search

Comment: Hi
ldap_count_entries($connect, $search) returns 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
...
$info = ldap_get_entries($connect, $search);
print_r($info);
for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
...
```

Also try assigning your givenname, sn and mail first in the loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
extract($info[$i]);
$email = $mail[0];
   echo"<h3>Requestor Info</h3>";
   echo "<div class=\"col1\">First Name:" . "<span class=\"req-firstname\">" . $givenname[0]. "</span></div>";
   echo "<div class=\"col1\">Last Name:" . "<span class=\"req-lastname\">" . $sn[0]. "</span></div>";
   echo "<div class=\"col1\">Email: " . "<span class=\"req-email\">" . $email. "</span></div>";

 //How to populate variable email to get value from the LDAP Mail attribute
 }
```

See what results you get.

Comment: Hi
Thanks so much, that seems to be working. I am not sure exactly how the Extract function works. Can anyone explain?